# Method Syntax in Object Literal notation?

Tags: javascript, function, methods, object-literal

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm having a little trouble with execution context; the value of `this`.

Consider the following:

```
const name = "Mary";

const proto = { 
  hello: () => `Hello, my name is ${ this.name }.`
};

const greeter = name => Object.assign(Object.create(proto), { name }); 

const joe = greeter("Joe");

console.log(joe.hello());
```

I expected the log would be: `Hello, my name is Joe.` But `this` was instead the global object. It returned `Hello, my name is Mary.`

On the other hand:

```
const name = "Mary";
const proto = { 
  hello() { return `Hello, my name is ${ this.name }.` }
};

const greeter = name => Object.assign(Object.create(proto), { name }); 

const joe = greeter("Joe");

console.log(joe.hello());
```

This time the expected string was returned; the only difference is the "method definition" inside the proto object.

So my question is what is the second syntax even called?
It is not a function declaration nor a function expression, so what is it? Either way I expected the property accessor invocation from the 'greeter' object, 'joe' to associate `this` to the object itself.

And when should I use a function expression and when should I use this alternative form of declaring an object's method?

I hope this makes sense and thank you in advance for you attention.

Comment: The second variant is just `method shorthand`, it's just the shorthand for `const proto = {hello: function hello() {...`   Also `() => ` is called an arrow function and does not have it's own `this` and just keeps the current lexical `this`

Comment: `hello: () =>` is a property, but `hello() {` is a method

Comment: Thank you that answers my question. So my problem is the arrow function not that this *moethod shorthand* is not a function. Why didn't you post this in the answer?